# Magento SSL Issue

Tags: magento-1.9, ssl

magento assistance needed to help me to resolve ssl issue i'm facing on my magento store, i'm using Magento ver. 1.9.1.0 and i just notice https issue on my site, whenever i'm trying to loading any of my website page, using below links formate, it redirect me on home page.

http www.example.com/page (Working)
https example.com/page (redirect on home page)
http www.example.com/page (redirect on home page)
http example.com/page (redirect on home page)

Thank You

Comment: "http www.example.com/page (Working) " ... "http www.example.com/page (redirect on home page) " - what?

Comment: "http www.example.com/page (Working) " but when i add HTTPS  "https www.example.com/page (redirect on home page) "

Comment: Are you using apache or nginx? Can you post your vhost config files? What about the secure and unsecure url in core_config_data, what values do you currently have there? Did you make any changes to your .htaccess?

Comment: base url or rewrite rule  -  something incorrect

Answer (score 0):

First off just make some changes in .htaccess
Search for Options 
**+FollowSymLinks**
And put below code under it:

> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
>
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

If this do not work then you will have to check with second option.

Second you need to check your ssl.conf under your server virtual host directory nginx or apache:
Example:

> cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
>
> sudo nano example_ssl.conf

(example is domain reference for ssl, it can be anything you want.)
just check your site directory and https url configuration for domain name and url

Run this to enable and start SSL on server for above configuration:

> sudo a2enmod ssl

If you have anything to change in ssl.conf you will have to restart the server:

> sudo service apache2 restart